# Yew error – only one root html element allowed

Tags: html, rust, components, yew

I have encountered a problem with the Yew library's component mechanism. If I include any other html code in the macro for the main model's html macro, the compiler complains that "only one root html element allowed".

My structure is as follows:

**main.rs**

```
impl Component for Model {
    // ...

    fn view(&self) -> Html<Self> {
        html! {
            <Navigation />
            <p>{ "Hello World!" }</p>
        }
    }
}
```

**components/navigation.rs**

```
impl Component for Navigation {
    // ...

    fn view(&self) -> Html<Self> {
        html! {
            <nav class=("uk-navbar-container","uk-padding","uk-padding-remove-bottom","uk-padding-remove-top"), uk-navbar="">
                // ...
            </nav>
        }
    }
}
```

I am suspecting the html macro is adding a -tag or the whole index.html around the html tags, thus causing the "double" html tag. However, how can I avoid this or what did I miss when using components?

Comment: Can you just wrap the whole thing in a `div`? i.e in `main.rs` change the html to `<div><Navigation /><p>...</p><div>`

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix Okay, yes, this was the problem - I did not know (or misread) that these html-macros need  such enclosing elements. If you want to add this as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler complaint is about the yew `html!` macro must have one element enclosing everything.

So the fix for the error is to simply add a wrapper element like so:

**main.rs**

```
impl Component for Model {
    // ...

    fn view(&self) -> Html<Self> {
        html! {
            <div>
                <Navigation />
                <p>{ "Hello World!" }</p>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't have to be a `div`, it can be any html element.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before you need to wrap it. Yew supports JSX, you can do it like this:

```rust
impl Component for Model {
    // ...

    fn view(&self) -> Html<Self> {
        html! {
            <>
                <Navigation />
                <p>{ "Hello World!" }</p>
            </>
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer this way as it doesn't add any additional HTML to the rendered document. A `<div>` could eventually break existing CSS or JS. But if you write a completely new component it's also a good idea to always have only one wrapping HTML element per component (=use a div).